# Что будет хранить в себе ссылка после выполнения Class.forName(name).newInstance() на Java?

Tags: java

Я вот наткнулся на такой код и не могу понять как он работает. Что хранит в себе переменная  `dog` и что хранит в себе `name` ?

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
       Dog dog = null;

       String name = args[0]; // <----


       try {


          dog = (Dog) Class.forName(name).newInstance(); // <---


      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Comment: Экземпляр класса Dog и FQCN этого класса соответственно

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что в данной формулировке вопрос не полезен никому, кроме ТС, улучшен быть не может и должен быть предан забвению.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб "отсутствие пользы для кого-либо, кроме автора" не может являться причиной для таких действий.

Comment: @Etki, ну, на мете вот сейчас Николас пост про удаление вывесил. Там пишет: "Относительно вопросов, удаляются сообщения, которые не добавляют ничего нового на сайт.". И до моей правки заголовка и до выяснения, что гугл и текст ответа тоже проиндексирует, считаю, что закрытие вопроса было более чем уместно. А вообще, мы как раз в чате это всё сейчас обсуждаем)

Comment: Да обсуждайте что хотите, пока вопрос приносит пользу автору, удалять его может только тот, кто пользуется ресурсом ради ощущения власти.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб то, что ответ на вопрос поможет лишь одному человеку, не может быть причиной закрытия и удаления. Если вы считаете что это не так - проведите изменение правил/онтопика через обсуждение на мете.

Comment: @PashaPash, насколько я понимаю правила, вопрос был вне правил, пока в нём не был исправлен заголовок и пока меня не уверили, что гугл проиндексирует и ответ помимо вопроса. Голос отозвал. Но то, что без заголовка изменённого и факта индексации ответа поисковиками вопрос имеет ценность стремящуюся к нулю, всё ещё щитаю)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`main(String[] args)` - точка входа в программу. В `args` лежат аргументы командной строки. 
К примеру, при вызове вашей программы таким образом:

```
java -jar my_app.jar com.myapp.SuperDog
```

В `args[0]` будет строка `com.myapp.SuperDog`. Соответственно, в строке `name` будет значение `com.myapp.SuperDog`.

С помощью методов `Class.forName()` и `newInstance()` объекта `Class` можно динамически загружать и создавать экземпляры класса в случае, когда имя класса неизвестно до момента выполнения программы. Это часть Java Reflection API.

В данном случае, создаётся экземпляр класса `SuperDog`.

```
Class.forName(name).newInstance();
```

`(Dog)` - делает приведение типов. Сработает без проблем либо если у вас класс с именем `name` является наследником класса `com.myapp.Dog` или же если в `name` банально лежит строка `com.myapp.Dog`.

Предполагаю, что в программе используется наследование. И есть классы, наследующиеся от `Dog`. Что-то вроде такого класса в пакете `com.myapp`:

```
public class SuperDog extends Dog{

   [...]
}
```

и т.п.

Если же передать аргументом просто `com.myapp.Dog`, то создастся просто экземпляр этого класса.

Comment: Спасибо, все очень понятно! Только я не до конца понимаю как `args`, понимает какой класс ему передали. А если у меня несколько обьектов создается, какой он выберет? Подскажите как можно найти информацию? Почитать про то как это работает?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko `args` ни про какие классы не знает, это просто массив аргументов командной строки.

Comment: Параметр с названием этого класса я ввожу когда программа компилируется?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko когда запускаете программу.